# How the total order property of $\mathbb{R}$ is related to not being algebraicaly closed?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, field-theory

[The field of real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) $\mathbb{R}$ is [total-ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) and not algebraicaly closed, [the field of complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered but is [algebraicaly closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field).

Intuitively how these two properties are related?

For example:

1. what about other fields, how the two properties relate?
2. is there any algebraicaly closed field that is ordered?
3. why ordering breaks closure? (if indeed so) (some intuitive argument will do)
4. why closure breaks ordering? (if indeed so) (some intuitive argument will do)
5. is it true that $\mathbb{C}$ cannot have any kind of order? (what about ordering by magnitude and (sub-ordering by) phase, for example)
6. does this have any relation to [automorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_automorphism) of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$? (i.e [conjugate numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate))
7. ...

This follows on a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810460/how-exactly-is-i-sqrt-1-related-to-mathbbc-being-a-closed-algebraic-fi)

Adding Gerry Myerson's comments as an answer to this question so any other people that might see this, see an actual answer. (so please dont thank or upvote me for the answer)

> Any algebraically closed filed will have an element whose square is
>   minus one,  so being an ordered field isn't going to happen
>
> Of course, the complex numbers can have "an order", but an ordered
>   field is one in which the order and the field operations work
>   together, and that's the kind of order the complex numbers can't have.
>
> There are only 2 field automorphisms of the complex numbers over the
>   reals: the identity, and complex conjugation. Similarly, there are 2
>   field automorphisms of the rationals adjoin 2√ over the rationals, but
>   those fields are both ordered, so I don't see much joy there.

PS As Gerry Myerson said, "*lets wait and see if sth better comes along*"..

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but existence of roots of equations that "should" always be positive (e.g. $x^2 + 1$) is what breaks a hypothetical ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ - one standard proof that $\mathbb{C}$ isn't ordered is to establish that neither $i < 0$ nor $i > 0$ can hold.

Comment: @user61527, yeap this is true, i am looking for a more intuitive conceptualization, will link a related question

Comment: You're looking for a "more intuitive conceptualization" than what user61527 explained? His or her explanation was already intuitive and concise and gets to the heart of the matter: it is a perfect and complete answer.

Comment: @seaturtles, the question provides several points of view (which at least for me make a more intuitive question), i know the definition, now i want to understand it better (esp from these points of view)

Comment: *Any* algebraically closed filed will have an element whose square is minus one, so being an ordered field isn't going to happen

Comment: Of course, the complex numbers can have "an order", but an *ordered field* is one in which the order and the field operations work together, and that's the kind of order the complex numbers can't have.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, very nice, elaborated in simple terms, it is nice for me as an answer, what about the C automorphisms, related in any way?

Comment: There are only 2 field automorphisms of the complex numbers over the reals: the identity, and complex conjugation. Similarly, there are 2 field automorphisms of the rationals adjoin $\sqrt2$ over the rationals, but those fields are both ordered, so I don't see much joy there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, ok want to add it as an answer?

Comment: I'd rather see you add it as an answer, give yourself practice in writing things up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, ok i will your comments as an answer so other people can see an actual answer, but i dont want to type too much, i am not a typist :)

Comment: Typing is also worth practicing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, if you want to answer a question, answer a question because you want to answer, is this sth personal are you the same guy over my Goedel question or am i mistaken?

Comment: I don't remember a Godel question. If my name is there, that's me. I just think it's great when people can see how to answer their own questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks but your comments did not answer all my questions, they did answer literally the points but not in the depth i had in mind, nevertheless i accept because i know you cant do better than that (at least at this point)

Comment: Then let's wait and see whether something better comes along.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, ok will it leave there, but if you want we can take this into a chat, i feel you want to say more..